# How to inhibit multiselect with SWFUpload

Tags: swfupload

SWFU.selectFile() doesn't work anymore due to changes in security model.

User click on the movie opens the dialog but I need to inhibit multi-select.

I have tried the following options to no avail:

- file_upload_limit
- file_queue_limit

It is not evident to me from the documentation which option inhibits multi-select. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it in the source code, searching for "button". The default is

```
button_action: SWFUpload.BUTTON_ACTION.SELECT_FILES
```

and there is a value defined

```
SWFUpload.BUTTON_ACTION.SELECT_FILE
```